# PowerShell Logging (verbose)

Tags: powershell, logging, logfile, verbose

I want to log my PowerShell scripts.
Now I have discovered the Verbose paramteter for myself.

The script currently looks like this (sample script):

```
try {
    New-Item "D:\Test.txt" -ItemType "File" -ErrorAction Stop -Verbose
}
catch {
    Write-Host $Error[0] -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

The output then looks like this:

```
VERBOSE: Execute the "Create file" operation for the target "Target: D:\Test.txt".

    Directory: D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       03.05.2020     18:09              0 Test.txt
```

I want the output to appear in the console and also be written to a log file.
The output should look like this:

Console:

```
VERBOSE: Execute the "Create file" operation for the target "Target: D:\Test.txt".
```

Log file:

```
01.01.2020      12:00       Execute the "Create file" operation for the target "Target: D:\Test.txt".
```

You shouldn't see issues like this.

```
    Directory: D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       03.05.2020     18:09              0 Test.txt
```

How do I do that?
Is there also a possibility not to have to write a "verbose" after every command?

Thank you!

Comment: For logging, I would recommend using `PSFramework` library. It has a `Write-PSFMessage` and `Get-PSFMessage` function. For the long run that may be the better option.

Comment: Could you demonstrate that with an example?

Comment: @Alex - have you looked at the module in question? it seems to have a reasonable set of examples ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Alex, it is fairly straight forward. Use, the write function to create your logging information and finally output everything you want with `Get-PSFMessage` to a file or whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find what official documentation on PSFramework logging exists here:

> https://psframework.org/documentation/documents/psframework/logging.html

Basically, what you do at the beginning of your script is defining where the logs should go using `Set-PSFLoggingProvider`, then use `Write-PSFMessage` to write things.
Using a logfile is the most common scenario, but many other targets are supported out of the box (Eventlog, Splunk, Azure Log Analytics and more).

Let's go with [logfile](https://psframework.org/documentation/documents/psframework/logging/loggingto/logfile.html) for an example:

```
$paramSetPSFLoggingProvider = @{
    Name         = 'logfile'
    InstanceName = 'MyTask'
    FilePath     = 'C:\Logs\TaskName-%Date%.csv'
    Enabled      = $true
}
Set-PSFLoggingProvider @paramSetPSFLoggingProvider
```

With that the logging is enabled and any messages generated will then be written to the file "C:\Logs\TaskName-.csv.

To [write messages](https://psframework.org/documentation/documents/psframework/logging/basics/writing-messages.html), you can now:

```
# Default verbose message
Write-PSFMessage "Hello"

# Visible to user by default
Write-PSFMessage -Level Host -Message "Alex"

# Add some extra info
try { 1/0 }
catch { Write-PSFMessage -Level Warning -Message "Tried to do the impossible" -ErrorRecord $_ -Tag 'failed','impossible' }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7) can be used for.

> 'Saves command output in a file or variable and also sends it down the
>   pipeline.'

Examples

```
<#
Example 1: Output processes to a file and to the console
This example gets a list of the processes running on the computer and sends the result to a file. Because a second path is not specified, the processes are also displayed in the console.
#>

Get-Process | 
Tee-Object -FilePath "C:\Test1\testfile2.txt"


Example 2: Output processes to a variable and `Select-Object`

This example gets a list of the processes running on the computer, saves them to the $proc variable, and pipes them to Select-Object.
#>

Get-Process notepad | 
Tee-Object -Variable proc | 
Select-Object processname,handles


<#
Example 3: Output system files to two log files

This example saves a list of system files in a two log files, a cumulative file and a current file.
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path D: -File -System -Recurse |
Tee-Object -FilePath "c:\test\AllSystemFiles.txt" -Append |
Out-File c:\test\NewSystemFiles.txt
```

Though the PSFramework that Alex_P is pointing you to is more elegant.

> [Logging Done Right with PowerShell and the PSFramework Module](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-logging)